# Regex match string that starts with but does not include

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match file paths that start with any string from a list. This is what I am using for that:

```
^/(dir1|dir2|dir3|tmp|dir4)/
```

I'm also trying to match all paths that start with `/tmp/` but do not contain `special` after that.

This should match:

```
/tmp/subdir/filename.ext
```

But this should not:

```
/tmp/special/filename.ext
```

I can't seem to find a way to get this done. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A negative lookahead that is if your regex engine supported it `(?!special)`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex lookahead, lookbehind and atomic groups](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `^(?i)/(dir1|dir2|dir3|tmp(?!\/(special))|dir4)/.*`

`(?i)` = Case insesitivity this will match SpEcial, SPECial, SpEcIAL etc.

`(?!\/(special))` = *Negative lookahead* for the `'/special'`

Comment: This answer works just as well in my case, as the one from @grexter89 (since I need the match to be case sensitive), but your's is more comprehensive. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

try this

```
^((?:dir1|dir2|dir3|dir4|tmp(?!/special)).*)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/1Oese7JhabcvTxzi)

Comment: Can you explain '?:' I have not seen this used before?

Comment: (?:....) builds a group, but it doesn't create a reference, so there's no special result for the expression inside the brackets

Answer (score 1):

try this `^(dir1|dir2|dir3|tmp(?!\/special)|dir4)`