# Regex matching everything that does NOT start with X OR contains Y

Tags: java, regex

I want a regular expression to match everything that does not start with X or contains Y.

I currently have the first part: `^(?!X).*$`

This will match anything not starting with X. However, I can't get the second part working. I have tried the solution here:

[Regex match string that starts with but does not include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19789335/regex-match-string-that-starts-with-but-does-not-include)

but with no luck.

**Test cases**

*Don't match on*:

```
X
XBLABLA
```

*Match on:*

```
XY
BLABLA
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `^(?!X).*|.*Y.*$`  - that `|` means "or".

Comment: It should be `^(?:(?!X)|.*Y).*$`

Comment: I know regular expression puzzles are fun, but how about `if (s.contains("Y") || !s.startsWith("X"))` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?:(?!X)|.*Y).*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CaFAMq/1/)

In Java, when using `matches`, the anchors are not necessary at the start/end:

```
s.matches("(?s)(?:(?!X)|.*Y).*")
```

The `(?s)` will allow matching strings containing line breaks.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string (implicit in `matches`)
- `(?:(?!X)|.*Y)` - either a position not followed with `X` immediately to the right, or any 0+ chars as many as possible and then `Y`
- `.*` - the rest of the string (it is necessary if the regex is used with `matches`, it is not necessary with `find` as the latter does not require the full string match)
- `$` - end of string (implicit in `matches`)

Comment: Thank you for the answer + explanation. This worked.